# How to set the animation duration to match the page load time on the fly?

Tags: javascript, css, transition

For example, I have a preloader div which is hidden with addClass on $(window).load() - fairly routine stuff.

Now, in addition to this I want to include a loading bar or similar with a css transition within the preloader - also fairly easy assuming I have a fixed duration that would hopefully accommodate the majority of load times.

The issue now is that I want the animation to **complete** every time, regardless of page load time - how do I set the animation duration to match the page load time on the fly?

Comment: Page load times are between 0 and infinity.  Hmm....

Comment: This is true, it would need to include a simple 'timeout' after a few seconds.. can't imagine that would be too tricky?

Comment: Why not set a very long interval for the progress bar, then, on `$(window).load` run a function to ratchet the progress bar quickly up to 100% before running any other scripts on the page?

Comment: @sideroxylon Whilst more or a workaround, I've a feeling this may be the best solution!

Comment: Yep.  Hard to time to infinity.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for this the solution, as described by sideroxylon would be  something along these lines:

```
// Kick off animation with long duration on doc ready
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#progress-bar > div').animate({'width':'100%'}, 40000);
});

// When the page has loaded clearQueue and stop the animation, 
// then resume with much shorter duration to complete

$(window).load(function() {
   $('#progress-bar > div').clearQueue().stop();
   $('#progress-bar > div').animate({'width':'100%'}, 500);
});
```

Hope this is of use!